# Xamarin.Forms ScrollView - animate its growth as it expands

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms

We've got a ScrollView which I've set with a VerticalOptions of "End", so that when we add content to it at runtime it 'grows' from the bottom.

We're scrolling to the end when adding content, with animation. This looks good when the ScrollView is full and is actually scrolling.

However, when content is added to the ScrollView, the new content appears immediately with no animation.

Any thoughts on how to animate the growth of the ScrollView as the new content is added? Ideally I'd like it to slide up, like the animated scroll when it's full.

We're using a RepeaterView as the content of the ScrollView, if that's relevant.

Relevant existing code below (we're using Forms with MvvmCross - hence an MVVM pattern):

**ViewModel**

```
    private async Task NextClick()
    {

        var claimFlowQuestion = await GetClaimFlowQuestion(_currentIndexQuestion);

        Questions.Add(ClaimFlowExtendFromClaimFlow(claimFlowQuestion));

        // Trigger PropertyChanged so the Repeater updates
        await RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Questions));

        // Trigger the QuestionAdded event so the ScrollView can scroll to the bottom (initiated in the xaml.cs code behind)
        QuestionAdded?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());

    }
```

**XAML**

```
        <ScrollView  Grid.Row="1" x:Name="QuestionScrollView">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End"
                Padding  ="10,0,10,0"
                IsVisible="{Binding Busy, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBooleanConvertor}}}">
                <controls:RepeaterView
                    x:Name="QuestionRepeater"
                    Margin      ="10"
                    AutomationId="IdQuestions"
                    Direction   ="Column"
                    ItemsSource ="{Binding Questions}"
                    ClearChild  ="false">
                    <controls:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <controlsClaimFlowControls:QuestionBlock
                                    Margin             ="0,20,0,20"
                                    QuestionNumber     ="{Binding Index}"
                                    QuestionText       ="{Binding QuestionText}"
                                    QuestionDescription="{Binding QuestionDescription}"
                                    ItemsSource        ="{Binding Source}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath  ="{Binding DisplayPaths}"
                                    QuestionType       ="{Binding QuestionType}"
                                    SelectedItem       ="{Binding Value}"
                                    IsEnabledBlock     ="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                </controls:RepeaterView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

**XAML.cs**

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        if (BindingContext != null)
        {
            MedicalClaimConditionPageModel model = (MedicalClaimConditionPageModel)this.BindingContext.DataContext;

            model.QuestionAdded += Model_QuestionAdded;
        }

        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        MedicalClaimConditionPageModel model = (MedicalClaimConditionPageModel)this.BindingContext.DataContext;

        model.QuestionAdded -= Model_QuestionAdded;
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }

    void Model_QuestionAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                // We need a Task.Delay to allow the contained controls to repaint and have their new sizes
                // Ultimately we should come up with a better resolution  - the delay value can vary depending on device and OS version.

                await Task.Delay(50);
            }

            await QuestionScrollView.ScrollToAsync(QuestionRepeater, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Adding the relevant code would help too! And secondly, for this, you will have to work on the animation in the part of the code that adds the items in the RepeaterView's children stack!

Comment: @G.hakim Good point on the code - I've added the relevant parts of my existing code. As you say, it'll need to be where I add to the bound List which feeds the RepeaterView - but I think the animation will need to be driven from the xaml.cs

Comment: According to me, the better solution of doing this would be in the repeater view where it adds the newly added children to its ViewStack, Hope i am making sense!!!

Comment: Aha! Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for the idea/pointer.

Comment: Sure, if you could just share the animation code may be i can incorporate it in the repeater for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable answer has been posted by user yelinzh on the Xamarin forums:

> How about trying to use Custom Renderer such as the fading effect.
>
> ```
> [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScrollView_), typeof(ScrollViewR))]
> namespace App3.Droid
> {
>     public class ScrollViewR : ScrollViewRenderer
>     {
>         public ScrollViewR(Context context) : base(context)
>         {
>         }
>
>         protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
>         {
>             base.OnElementChanged(e);
>             this.SetFadingEdgeLength(300);
>             this.VerticalFadingEdgeEnabled = true;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> [image]

This would probably work. In fact we've got for a different approach 
(after feedback from the customer), where we're keeping the current question at the top of the screen and scrolling off upwards, so the content is no longer expanding.